# preseed uninstall

Tags: package-management, uninstall, preseed

I'm having a problem with my preseed file for Ubuntu 20.04.

I'm trying to remove Rhythmbox, Thunderbird, Libreoffice and Remmina which are installed by default (I first checked on an install the package names), so I wrote :

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
in-target apt remove -y --purge rhythmbox thunderbird libreoffice-core remmina
```

Everything is going fine and as soon as I log in, it didn't work at all, everything I wanted to delete is there :(

Could somebody please help me? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you have the logs from the installation? These could be snaps.

Comment: Where did i find them ?

Comment: I found the /var/log/installer/syslog file : https://pastebin.com/5tUSSTja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution ! I replaced *`d-i preseed/late_command string in-target`* by **`ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string in-target`** and it works :D